# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.4.0.0, The system cannot find the file specified.",

Tags: c#, botframework

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new DialogsHelper.EchoDialog());
            }
            else
            {
                this.HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
```

I am using visual studio 2015 and microsoft bot simulator.
This is response from bot simulator. 
I tried to install

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Bot.Builder
```

I am getting this error :

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder
>   3.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are  compatible with
>   that framework. For more information, contact the package author. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.Bot.Builder
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

when this line is commented,

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new DialogsHelper.EchoDialog());
```

simulators response is 200, that is OK.

in this dialogshelper namespace, i have this simple class :

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace MessengerBot.Helpers
{
    public class DialogsHelper
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class EchoDialog : IDialog<object>
        {
            public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
            {
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
            public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
            {
                var message = await argument;
                await context.PostAsync("You said: " + message.Text);
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The idea : I want to use Microsoft Bot Dialogs. 
I am following this tutorial [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dialogs.html).

How to solve this ?

Comment: Your question should explain the connection of the code fragment to the install error.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the properties of your csproj and change the Target Framework of the project to .NET Framework 4.6

[image: Target Framework]